# Public key encryption and big files with NaCL

Tags: encryption, public-key

I am trying to encrypt big files using NaCL (actually PyNaCL) - see http://nacl.cr.yp.to/box.html

After reading some docs, I came up with this prototype :

Bob wants to send a big file to Sarah. They both have a public/private key pair.

- set "position" to 0
- for each 256ko file chunk

  - generate a random nonce
  - append to the chunk 10 bytes containing position zfilled with zeroes
  - encrypt the chunk using crypto_box (using Bob private key and Sarah public key)
  - increment position

When Sarah gets the encrypted chunks:

- set "position" to 0
- for each encrypted chunk

  - decrypt the chunk using crypto_box (using Bob pub key and Sarah priv key)
  - extract the position and assert it's equal to "position"
  - increment position

prototype code here : https://github.com/tarekziade/fxakeys/blob/master/fxakeys/crypto.py#L119

What do you think ?

Comment: 1) Do you use a two part nonce, so you can use a different counter as nonce input for each chunk? Reusing the full nonce is fatal. 2) It's essential to use a special counter/nonce for the chunk containing the hash 3) I'd replace the hash by the file size

Comment: I used the same nonce through the whole process. Can you explain me why it is fatal in this case ? (or if you have a good link) - thanks for the feedback

Comment: 1) Salsa20 is a stream cipher, so nonce reuse behaves like one-time-pad key-reuse. http://crypto.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bone-time-pad%5D+%5Bkey-reuse%5D+is%3Aquestion 2) The Poly1305 MAC is a one-time MAC (wegman-carter), so nonce reuse leaks the MAC key for that nonce.

Comment: Thx - will read up

Comment: In your solution, if a malicious user is able to tamper with/replace your contents (encrypted chunk), it is not clear if he is also able to replace the hash. Unless you are transmiting/storing that separatedly, the hash is not improving your security... =)

Comment: Hbas, the hash was replaced by an autoinc, that is added to the data *before* encryption, so as far as I get it, this prevents tampering. I am also planning to add the total number of chunks so none can be appended

Comment: Verifying "the order of chunks" is not enough; you should also verify the chunks. $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer since it's encrypted with the pub/priv key pair, being able to decrypt it verifies it, no ? or do you mean something specific?

Comment: "being able to decrypt it" certainly doesn't verify it, especially since the encryption is public key. $\hspace{.6 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer so what should I do ?

Comment: You should [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) an ordered pair that indicates the autoinc and the ciphertext. $\;$

Comment: ok thx - will look at this

Comment: @RickyDemer reading back some crypto doc. I am confused why I need to verify the chunks. Public key encryption is done with the source private key and the target public key, and the decryption step ensures mutual authentication. So that guarantees the chunks are not forged. Why do I need to add an extra step here ?

Comment: No, public "key encryption is done with" ["the target public key"] and randomness and the message. $\:$ Signcryption adds in "the source private key" so that "the decryption step" will ensure "mutual authentication", which will guarantee that "the chunks are not forged". $\:$ You "need to add an extra step" into your question so that people know you're using signcryption rather than just PKE. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: The security model I use is described here: http://nacl.cr.yp.to/box.html (security model section) "The sender and receiver are nevertheless protected against forgeries by other parties." - I will clarify my initial question. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Do you know how big the file is before you encrypt it?

Comment: @CodesInChaos yes. so yea your proposal to use the file size makes a lot of sense, alongside the counter

Comment: If you want to detect truncation, but you don't want to require knowing the file size in advance, another option is to encrypt an empty chunk at the end.

Answer (score 4):

You're vulnerable to a chunk-level replay attack, where Mallory (the man-in-the-middle) can mix and match chunks from different files, to produce a file that appears to be from Bob but which Bob never wrote.

1. Bob sends two messages to Sarah. Let's say the first message comes in chunks A1 and A2, and the second message comes in chunks B1 and B2.
2. Mallory intercepts both messages. She then constructs the new message A1+B2.
3. Mallory sends the forged message to Sarah. The boxes open with Bob's key, and the sequence numbers look good.

Since Mallory can forge a message, this scheme fails to provide authenticity.

You could fix this problem in a couple ways. One way would be to put another token inside each chunk, next to the position bytes, that's shared by all the chunks and unique for each message. Then in addition to verifying the position, the receiver would have to check that this identifier matched the previous chunks.

Another approach would be to use NaCl's nonce to do this for you. (Since after all, a "unique token for each message" is sort of what a nonce is.) If you use 16 random bytes (shared by all the chunks) plus an 8-byte counter as your nonce, you can avoid nonce reuse and also prevent the chunk-swapping replay attack. This saves you some space because you only have to transmit the 16 random bytes once, and it's also safer: a forged plaintext will never be decrypted at all, so it's impossible for an implementation to somehow forget to check the tokens. This sort of use case is why NaCl was designed with a large nonce.

Edit: Adam Langley has a post on this: https://www.imperialviolet.org/2015/05/16/aeads.html